# Up-to-date TUGboat bibliography database

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, tugboat

Where can I find machine-readable bibliographic data for at least all publicly-available TUGboat articles?

I've found [CTAN:/info/digests/tugboat/t-of-c/](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/digests/tugboat/t-of-c/), but that doesn't seem to have been updated since 2005, so I imagine there must be something newer, somewhere? (Perhaps the README there should refer to the newer thing?)

(Note that HTML doesn't count unless it's reasonably simple to extract the bibliographic data from the DOM/infoset.)

Comment: I'm not really sure this is on topic...

Comment: @Seamus: I'd say TUG is rather directly connected to TeX and hence on-topic.

Comment: @Caramdir It is connected to TeX, sure. But it doesn't seem to fit into any of the categories mentioned in the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: This is the first time I *removed* the `{biblatex}` tag.

Comment: I've e-mailed Karl Berry to see if one can be located

Comment: To follow up on that last comment, it seems that the latest version available is indeed the one mentioned in the question. So you'll have to type in the information you want by hand, at least at the moment.

Comment: @Joseph: Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @Caramdir: done.

Comment: @Caramdir: On the 'on topic' issue, I guess one could argue that it relates to CTAN and the availability of current material, which would be on topic. It's a marginal one, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking with Karl Berry (TUG President), it seems that the latest version available is indeed the one mentioned in the question. So you'll have to type in the information you want by hand, at least at the moment.

Comment: Did he mentioned why they don't give this information out any longer?

Answer (score 5):

A cumulative TUGboat bibliography, in BibTeX format, is compiled by Nelson Beebe at the University of Utah, and updated whenever a new issue is published and he receives the official contents file from the TUGboat production group.  The latest edition can be found at

ftp://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/tugboat.bib

Many institutions exclude links to ftp sites.  I don't know a direct `http` link, but reached this site by connecting to http://www.math.utah.edu/ and searching for "TUGboat bibliography".  The first item listed in the answer identified the link shown above.

I'm not sure why this hasn't made its way to CTAN.

**update:**
Thanks to ShreevatsaR, we learn that one can replace
the initial `ftp:` by `http:`, which should work for
users who are shut out of ftp.  That gives this site:

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/tugboat.bib

**update (October 2023):**
Nelson Beebe's archive of BibTeX databases, at
https://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib 
is kept up to date as far as TUGboat is concerned.  In addition,
it holds many hundreds of carefully curated BibTeX files for other
publications of interest to users of (La)TeX.  There should be
no more problems with FTP.

Comment: For those who can't access over FTP: it's linked from [his bibliographies page](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/bibliographies.html), so direct link would be http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/tugboat.html for a HTML version or http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/tugboat.bib for the `.bib` file (i.e. just replace `ftp://` at the start of the URL with `http://`).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a `tugboat.bib` file produced from the mentioned `.cnt` files [on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/biblio/tugboat.bib), but it's dated 2007-07-13 and the content is most likely not any newer then 2005.

The HTML on the [Table of contents listing](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/contents.html) of TUGboat could be parsed easily enough and provide the basic data fields. Otherwise simply write them an e-Mail and ask about it.